# OWASP ZAP : How to perform authentication when API endpoint only accepts raw XML?

Tags: authentication, zap

I'm currently working at testing an Angular 6 application using OWASP ZAP. I really enjoy this tool, but like many of us, I struggle with the authentication part, and without it the whole tool turns into a nothing burger.

The login route is accessible on my `localhost` at `/login` and my API endpoint `https://api.example.com/auth` **only accepts raw XML** such as:

```
<EngineDocList>
  <DocVersion>1.0</DocVersion>
  <EngineDoc>
    ...
    <User>
      <Username>testuser</Username>
      <Password>test</Password>
      <CustomField DataType="S32">blablabla</CustomField>
    </User>
    ...
  </EngineDoc>
</EngineDocList>
```

I get a token in response, but the API requires it to be sent **in the body** as a field of each request rather than as an Authorization header.

Also, running the spider **does not give me any time to login manually**, and I can't really provide any string to tell if I'm logged in or logged out as my Angular app **is not server rendered**.

Comment: You can use a match&replace - I just found this one via a very quick and dirty google search: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsReplacerReplacer

Use this to inject the auth token into the request body.
There might be better options to do this. But this is the first one that came to my mind.